# WebRTC PeerConnection in Java SE

Tags: java, webrtc

I'm trying to find a library that will provide Web RTC components in Java on the desktop or server, not Java Script.
Google provides a library for Java on Android, but it's not available for Java SE, or Java EE.
Specifically I'm trying to use the RTCPeerConnection to record the stream, or use it as the remote stream on multiple peer connections from other clients in a multi-casting setup.

Does anyone know of a WebRTC library for Java?